# How to improve this xpath expression?

Tags: java, xpath

```
/web-app/filter/filter-class[text()="com.zide.AppFilter"]/following-sibling::init-param/param-name[text()="development.mode"]/following-sibling::param-value
```

Node to replace.

```
 <web-app>
  <!--  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Zide APP Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.zide.AppFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config-file</param-name>
      <param-value>*.jsp,*.js</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>development.mode</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
</webapp>
```

XML File size - 100kb.

No of lines in a file - 2600.

Time taken to execute the expression is ~213 milliseconds to execute .

Is there any way to optimize this expression in java.

Comment: How have you measured this? Are you sure you're not including parsing the XML file and compiling the XPath expression in the timing?

Comment: @millimoose 
It includes parsing and compiling time .

Comment: Can you provide us the test file?

Comment: @bharathi I/O, DOM parsing, and high-level APIs like XPath are inherently slow, and they're best used when you either don't care about speed, or when you can amortise the overhead by using the same DOM tree for many operations, and reusing the compiled queries. If you need throughput in this use case, use StAX. (If what you're trying to do is replace / remove some values from a DOM tree it should be a good choice.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that development.mode exists in one filter only, you can directly go for that, it would reduce the number of steps to reach the data.

```
//param-name[text()="development.mode"]/following-sibling::param-value
```

Comment: Hi @srini.venigalla 
It will be there in couple of nodes .